# First column in Column graph is being cut off using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

So i am doing a report that is taking the count for each day through a month.

The first of the month 2016-04-01 the column is being cut off because of where it located on the x-axis. When I add always include zero I get 2016-03-31 as the first date which I do not want.  I am not sure what to do. I am using scalar with the interval of days. I have tried category however it only shows days that have the values and not the whole month. 
[please, see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1Mz.png)
[image]

[another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3G5D.png)
[image: this is the image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following settings in Horizontal Axis Properties window:

[image]

And it produces this chart:

[image]

Note first and last bar don't overlap with y-axis and chart area borders.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: when i do that i only get the days that have a count in them.